# Regular Expression Steps

Tags: regex

When playing around with regex patterns on regex101, I found out the exact number of steps(if its about a position change in a string) to match the pattern is one unit more than anticipated. For example, even with the most simple patterns like /\w/, it's matched in 2 steps not one, as if it were two positions from the beginning of the match. I don't know the reason behind this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are "steps" in RegexBuddy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447805/what-are-steps-in-regexbuddy)

Comment: gonna have to say that excepted answer is wrorng

Comment: since regex101 is calculating _steps_ maybe yuo shuld email the authur for his descrepshun of a steep. Actualf speed is measured by the amount of independent states the engine traverses.